# Did Shisupala's soul get merged with Krishna upon being slain?

Tags: mahabharata, krishna, moksha

Shisupala was slain by Krishna. Is it true that when he died, his atma merged with Krishna (indicating that he got Moksha)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes-

> *Having said this, the chief of the Yadus, that slayer of all foes, in anger, instantly cut off the head of the ruler of Chedi by means of his discus. And the mighty-armed one fell down like a cliff struck with thunder. **And, O monarch, the assembled kings then beheld a fierce energy, like unto the sun in the sky, issue out of the body of the king of Chedi, and O king, that energy then adored Krishna, possessed of eyes like lotus leaves and worshipped by all the worlds, and entered his body.***
>
> Mahabharata Sabha Parva Shishupala Vadha Parva [Section XLIV](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-mahabharata-mohan/d/doc6188.html)